# How to append the dataframe in to the excel sheet

Tags: excel, pandas, export-to-excel

I have a excel sheet having 5 sheets (sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,sheet4,final_df)

my dataframe `df` is the output, I need to save as `final_df` as sheet name. The final_df is already exist in the excel file with 4 line of data.so 'final_df` has append from the 5th row

How to achieve this?

While using excelwriter all the data from the sheet is vanishing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
book = load_workbook('final_df.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('final_df.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book

# get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
startrow = writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row

df.to_excel(writer,['Sheet1'], startrow, index = False, header= False)
writer.save()
```